# Merge Sort not working as expected in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mergesort

I have been debugging this code for hours but not getting whats wrong.
items is the list of div elements with randomly initiated heights.
Can someone help me, I am not able to find what is the problem with this code?

```
mergeSort1(l, r) {
    if (l < r) {
        let mid = Math.floor((l + r) / 2)
        this.mergeSort1(l, mid)
        this.mergeSort1(mid + 1, r)
        this.merge1(l, mid, r)
    }
}
merge1(l, mid, r) {
    let items = document.getElementsByClassName("item")
    items = Array.from(items)
    let left = items.slice(l, mid + 1)
    let right = items.slice(mid + 1, r + 1)
    let I = 0
    let J = 0
    let k = 0
    let t = []
    
    while (I < left.length && J < right.length) {
        if (parseInt(left[I].style.height) < parseInt(right[J].style.height)) {
            t.push(left[I].style.height)
            items[k + l].style.height = left[I].style.height
            I = I + 1
            k++
        } else {
            items[k + l].style.height = right[J].style.height
            t.push(right[J].style.height)
            J = J + 1
            k++
        }
    }
    while (I < left.length) {
        items[k + l].style.height = left[I].style.height
        k++
        t.push(left[I].style.height)
        I = I + 1
    }
    while (J < right.length) {
        items[k + l].style.height = right[J].style.height
        t.push(right[J].style.height)
        J = J + 1
        k++
    }
    console.log(t)
}
this.mergeSort1(0, this.state.arr.length - 1)
```

`arr` initialized in `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    //this.step(this)
    
    var a = []
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        a.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 80))
    }
    this.setState({
        arr : a
    }, () => console.log(this.state.arr))
}
```

In `render` Method:

```
arr.map((h, i) => {
        return (
            <div className="item" key={i} style={{height:h+'vh'}}>
            </div>)
   })
```

Input:

```
arr = [ 52, 68, 34, 60, 60, 42, 72, 70, 76, 52, 53, 51, 62, 47, 73, 44, 30, 0, 27, 25, 45, 40, 39, 12, 33, 33, 41, 74, 10, 30, 48, 17, 21, 7, 29, 33, 32, 56, 79, 29, 36, 16, 79, 68, 44, 37, 34, 36, 4, 35, 59, 54, 2, 11, 56, 78, 25, 16, 9, 69, 39, 80, 48, 5, 34, 68, 68, 21, 48, 42, 75, 57, 8, 76, 20, 76, 59, 50, 3, 52, 13, 7, 19, 6, 20, 72, 76, 46, 23, 10, 43, 16, 50, 16, 15, 58, 63, 53, 11, 52, …]
```

Output(log of div heights after `mergeSort`):

```
["0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "0vh", "1vh", "1vh", "1vh", "35vh", "35vh", "66vh", "70vh"]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use your own custom mergesort implementation, instead of passing a custom comparator into [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

Comment: Yes i am visualizing the merge sort. So i need each step.

Comment: If your mergesort function was fixed so that it sorted correctly, you wouldn't see each step. The sort would happen in one go: you'd initially see the divs with their starting height, and the next thing you would see after that would see the final result.  If you want to visualise mergesort you've got more work to do.  In particular, you will also need to define what you mean by 'step'.

Comment: I know how to visualize the algorithm, but before that i need the algorithm to work in one go like you said. Then i will visualize it. But the sort isn't working. Can you help find mistake in the algorithm?

Comment: Have i implemented the merge sort correctly is my question because its not working.

Comment: If it's not working then surely you haven't implemented mergesort correctly?  By the way, don't attempt to debug your code with your array `a` set to a list of 200 random numbers.  Instead, set `a` to a small constant array (e.g. `[4, 1]`) and focus on getting your code sorting that correctly.  Once it's working with `[4, 1]`, try some slightly larger arrays, until it works for those as well.

Comment: I did i am getting corret ans for array of size 2 but for greater sizes i am not getting correct ans? Do you see any mistakes in my code.? Because i think i am doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to sort an array of DOM elements by height, doing this by mutating the heights set in their style.  This causes two problems:

1. `Array.from` and `items.slice` will create new arrays, but they do not create copies of the DOM elements they contain.   So when you assign to the height of an element, you are changing the height of an element somewhere else in `items`.  This could be an item yet to be sorted.
2. You are using React.  You should let React control the DOM: you tell your components how to render themselves given some state and let React figure out how to change the DOM.

If however you focus your code on sorting the list of numbers in `this.state.arr`, then your code works.   In your `merge1` method, get rid of your array `items`, replace any reference to `items` with `this.state.arr` and remove all the uses of `.style.height` and `parseInt`:

```
merge1(l, mid, r) {
    let left = this.state.arr.slice(l, mid + 1)
    let right = this.state.arr.slice(mid + 1, r + 1)
    let I = 0
    let J = 0
    let k = 0
    let t = []
    
    while (I < left.length && J < right.length) {
        if (left[I] < right[J]) {
            t.push(left[I])
            this.state.arr[k + l] = left[I]
            I = I + 1
            k++
        } else {
            this.state.arr[k + l] = right[J]
            t.push(right[J])
            J = J + 1
            k++
        }
    }
    while (I < left.length) {
        this.state.arr[k + l] = left[I]
        k++
        t.push(left[I])
        I = I + 1
    }
    while (J < right.length) {
        this.state.arr[k + l] = right[J]
        t.push(right[J])
        J = J + 1
        k++
    }
    console.log(t)
}
```

You might also want to consider using variable names that are more descriptive than `I`, `J`, `k`, `l`, `r` or `t`, and also document your code to make it clear that the parameter `r` in `mergeSort1` and `merge1` is 'inclusive', i.e. it points to the last element to be sorted rather than the first element beyond that.